# Component not defined after importing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a collapse/accordion component from Antd that I customized and exported from an elements folder from within my application so that I could reuse it across the app.

I used React Hooks within the component in order to elegantly apply a disabled/setDisabled effect to some text on the Panel header.

Now when I import the component and attempt to change the header property of the Panel I get an error:

> AntCollapse is not defined

If I simply import and place my custom collapse component the header is empty and malformed.

I've included my custom collapse file below along with the component I've attempted importing it into.

```
// @CustomCollapse
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Collapse as AntCollapse } from 'antd'

const StyledCollapse = styled(AntCollapse)`
  &&& {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
`

const CustomCollapse = props => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true)
  return (
    <StyledCollapse onChange={() => setDisabled(prev => !prev)}>
      <AntCollapse.Panel
        header={props.header}
        key="1"
        showArrow={false}
        bordered={false}
        extra={<p style={{ color: '#0076de' }}>{disabled ? 'SHOW' : 'HIDE'}</p>}
      />
    </StyledCollapse>
  )
}

export default CustomCollapse
```

```
// @App
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Col, Row } from 'antd'
import Checkbox from '../elements/Checkbox'
import icon from '../../assets/caretDown.svg'
import Button from '../elements/Button'
import CustomCollapse from '../elements/Collapse'

const ConfigurationOptions = ({ configuration, ...props }) => (

  <Container>
    <Row>
      <Col span={12}>
        <CustomCollapse>
          {/* <AntCollapse.Panel header="configuration test" /> */}
        </CustomCollapse>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
)

const Container = styled.div`
  text-align: left;
`

export default ConfigurationOptions
```

Comment: Please note to write a minimal and concise question, it's hard to follow your "story" (it's not the first time I edit your Q), moreover, always consider adding a sandbox like https://codesandbox.io/s/new, it makes other users life much easier.

Comment: Ok Dennis, appreciate the ongoing help. Is there a resource you can link to or a wiki with guidelines on how to be more succinct in crafting the perfect question and add things like error backgrounds such as the one you provided here for ```Antd collapse not defined```? Anything beyond the help center articles for Stack Overflow?

Comment: You got help panel https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking, and I answered your Q

Comment: Good deal, I'll be sure to leverage that as I write my new question relating to this problem. Thanks for feedback

Comment: Just posted a new question and took the time to make sure it was formatted properly, and I feel like a real stack overflow user now haha. Thanks again for the help and the callout man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AntCollapse` not defined because you didn't `import` it.

You used `export default CustomCollapse`, with default you can name your component as you like, so just:

```js
import AntCollapse from '../elements/Collapse'; // No CustomCollapse

const ConfigurationOptions = ({ configuration, ...props }) => (

  <Container>
    <Row>
      <Col span={12}>
        <AntCollapse>                           // CustomCollapse not defined
          <AntCollapse.Panel header="configuration test" />
        </AntCollapse>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
)

export default ConfigurationOptions
```

[image: Edit Q-56776002-Wrong-Import]